# Swift could not cast from Swift.X to Swift.X.Type

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm a newbie in Swift and probably I don't have the experience to understand how casting works in Swift, but I hope you can help me:

```
let x:Int32 = db.valueByKey(key: ["integer_tgc":Int32.self]).AtIndexT(index: [2:Int32.self]);
```

The AtIndexT is an extension and looks like this:

```
extension Array {

    func AtIndex(index: Int) -> Any {
        
        return self[index];
    }
    
    func AtIndexT<T>(index: KeyValuePairs<Int,T>) -> T? {
        
        if let _record = index.first {
            
            let _key : T = self[_record.key] as! T;
            return _key;
            
        } else {
            
            return nil;
        }
    }
}
```

So what I want to do is an generic call to get a specified item of the array which type I don't know.
I've learned that even in Swift 5.x generics doesn't work like in C# for example.

The compiler gives me for the example above
"Cannot convert value of type 'Int32.Type?' to specified type 'Int32'"

What does this mean?
What's the difference between X.Type and X, regardless the specific type. The valueByKey function returns [Int32], so I don't understand why I cannot pass the Int32.self (=Type) to the AtIndexT function which in turn interpreting Int32.self as T.
Then I grab the 2 (second) item of the array which was provided by dbValueByKey, cast with as! T and return.
But no matter  what I try, I cannot get this example to get working.

Interestingly that breaks Xcode 12.4 completely (internal error occurred):

```
let x:Int = Int(db.valueByKey(key: ["integer_tgc":Int32.self]).AtIndexT(index: [2:Int.self]));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're getting

> The compiler gives me for the example above "Cannot convert the value of type 'Int32.Type?' to specified type 'Int32'"

is because you are passing `Int32.self` as `T` in the `KeyValuePairs` as a parameter to your function so the return type which is `T?` itself becomes `Int32.Type?`. So when you are trying to assign it to `x` of type `Int32`, the compiler is throwing an error because the cast will fail.

So to solve this, you can prefer the below code:

Array extension:

```
extension Array {
    func AtIndex(index: Int) -> Any {
        return self[index];
    }

    func AtIndexT<T>(index: KeyValuePairs<Int, T.Type>) -> T? {
        if let _record = index.first {
            let _key : T = self[_record.key] as! T;
            return _key;        
        } else {
            return nil;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let x:Int32? = Int(db.valueByKey(key:["integer_tgc":Int32.self]).AtIndexT(index: [2:Int32.self]))
```

**Note:** `x` is of `Optional Int32` type.

Comment: Glad to know it helped!